# How do I upgrade git on Mac OS X?

Tags: upgrade, xcode

I have `git` on `/usr/bin/git` (I think was Xcode install) but it is 1.7.5.4 and I want to use the current version 1.7.7

Is there a way to uninstall that version and use the new one?

Answer (score 10):

None of the current answers will upgrade Xcode git. They will only install a newer version of git.

Xcode has changed its mind several times about the best git location. Depending on how long ago you have been installing Xcode you will see git binaries at:

```
/usr/bin/git
/usr/local/git
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git
```

Even if you update the PATH, Xcode will stick to its version. The only way I know to force it to use the newer version is replacing those git binaries by a link to the new one you installed.

```
ln -s /opt/local/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

Repeat for the other path. Notice I use a symbolic link, not a hard one. Otherwise Xcode would replace your other installation during an upgrade

Comment: Yeah, everyone says "just make sure PATH is in proper order", but that doesn't work with Xcode binaries, it seems.

Comment: The sym link will not work in Big Sur any longer, actually.

Answer (score 6):

You can install `git` from source using Homebrew, and just point your PATH to use the new one instead of the xcode/system version.

There's a little video tutorial here. http://vimeo.com/14649488

It's for an older version but it will get you started, let me know if you need more info.

<sup>(You can also use MacPorts, Fink or the Git OS X installer, to upgrade.)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use git itself to update git run the following commands :

This can be run from anywhere `git clone git://github.com/gitster/git.git`
then you want to `cd git` then run this `sudo make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info`

This will install Git into your /usr/bin folder for global use.

Comment: It's never a good idea to overwrite system binaries.  Much better to install into `/usr/local/bin` or `$HOME/bin` or similar and adjust your `PATH` accordingly.

Comment: As SystematicFrank said, even if you update the PATH, Xcode will stick to its version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a newer git than the one in Xcode then you need to install it, this install should be to another place as if you update `/usr/bin/git` then an Apple update will overwrite this version.

There are several ways to do this but as noted by @FranciscoGarcia they won't necessarily change the one used by Xcode just the command line version.

The easiest is to install the binaries from the [git](http://git-scm.com/) site.

If you want code then use a package manager e.g. Fink macports, Homebrew.

If you want the bleeding edge latest install from git's own repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest git using [macports](http://www.macports.org):

```
sudo port install git-core +svn +doc +bash_completion +gitweb
```

Comment: I understand that this might not be the best answer, but why is this -2?

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest binary from [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and install.